# Text Changed event of the textbox, inside border at row m and column of a grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a WPF Grid, created by code. Inside the grid cells, there are borders. Borders contain textboxes which have text.

I want to change the visibility of the text in the Textblock depending on its contents.
If the text changes, visibility too should change, depending on the new value of the text.

How to fire Text_Changed event? Will I have to crerate a new event? Should I be creating a rounted event or just a C# event.

Comment: Why the winforms and VB.net tag?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree Because this wpf window is hosted by a windows forms host. VB.NET because, I can translate it to C#.

Comment: Are you speacking of the visibility of the TextBox or of the visibility of the text insibe the textbox?

Comment: @Didier doesn't matter whether its visibility of the textblock or text. I would be hiding it not collapsing it. Oh btw sorry for the typo. Its a textblock not textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to bind textbox visibility to the text and to write a converter that will check the text and return an appropriate value for the visibility. Here is an example:

The converter:

```
public class TextToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value as string;

        //Write your condition here
        if (text == "foo")
            return Visibility.Hidden;
        else
            return Visibility.Visible;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the resource section you add:

```
<l:TextToVisibilityConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
```

And you set your TextBlock like this:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" .../>
```

In this way the visibility will be calculated inside the converter no matter how your text was changed. And you don't need TextChanged event for this.

If you need to create your binding in the code behind you can write something like this:

```
//Create just one instance of this converter and then reuse for all bindings.
IValueConverter converter = new TextToVisibilityConverter();

//Now you can bind the text and the visibility
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Text");
myBinding.Source = textBlock;
myBinding.Converter = converter;
textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.VisibilityProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: How to display the new value of text if text changes? I need a event like text)changed. Text_changed is not available.

Comment: Your text is not binded to a VM?

Comment: I've added some code to illustrate what I was saying.

Comment: I am binding the text in code, not xaml. Can you help me in binding the converter through code?

Comment: I am getting an error Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface while trying to create an instance of Binding class.

Comment: The binding you are probably using is System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding (not a WPF bingind) you should use System.Windows.Data.Binding. Here is the MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.100).aspx